# Deploying Prerender.io with Node.js on production

Tags: angularjs, node.js, heroku, single-page-application, prerender

I've been looking into using `prerender` for my Angular app, and having some trouble thinking about how to implement it on production and more specifically, Heroku.

So I understand from the documentation that on `localhost`, I can run my app on `localhost:9000` and then in another terminal run an instance of `prerender` on say `localhost:9001`. Then using the [prerender-node](https://github.com/prerender/prerender-node) middleware I can say the following:

`app.use(require('prerender-node').set('prerenderServiceUrl', 'http://localhost:9001'));`

What I don't understand is how I could run the `prerender` service on `localhost:9000` instead? I don't really want to setup an entirely new server just to run `prerender`. My biggest concern with a separate server is how would I call that in production? Would I have to set the URL as something like `my-prerender-server.com` which would requiring buying that domain? This may seem stupid but how can I keep it nice and simple? I would like to run it all from one app if possible...

Any ideas or tips?

Answer (score 0):

I use prerender and node-prerender to handle crawlers of my angular 1 app.

You need to make two servers listening to different domain/port. The easiest way, would be to create a subdomain like prerender.company.com, as this is free and should be easy to configure in your dns.

You can possibly run both servers in a single process using something like [vhost](https://github.com/expressjs/vhost) but it is easier and simpler to run two sepperate servers.

Comment: Could you expand a bit on your setup as you're using the self-hosted solution? When testing locally I literally just downloaded the demo `prerender` app and used a random command I saw online to bind the service to listen to `localhost:9000`. The `node-prerender` library looks like a simple case of just including one line of code to set your URL, but is there anything special you had to do when developing your solution?

Comment: `node-prerender` is a simple one-liner. The server is almost identical to the demo, and fairly easy to configure. You can change the port by setting `process.env.PORT` etc. In our angular app we use `window.prerenderReady = true` this allows us to set when all needed ressources for the prerender is loaded. We also set up the s3 cache plugin without any trouble.

Comment: Thanks, so `node-prerender` will determine if the request is from a bot or not. What kind of things do you check for when doing `window.prerenderReady = true`? And how would you pass this `prerenderReady` variable to the server so that it knows when to start rendering the HTML?

Comment: yes, `node-prerender` is simply a middle ware that checks if it should forward the request to the prerender server. `window-prerenderReady`is a variable you set in your angular app, to tell the server that all data is loaded. You don't have to set it, if you don't prerender will return the page when there are no outstanding requests, or after a certain time.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help :)